# Bad image and connection error when downloading League of Legends client 

Tags: league-of-legends, technical-issues

Trying to download League of Legends, which is where I was taken when I was done with creating an account. I got this error (first error) during the download process and by clicking "cancel" and "ok", it continues downloading so I pressed ok each time the error appeared. When it's finished, another error says (second error):

[image]

I'm on Windows 7 64 bit, if it matters.

Comment: Did you low the security of your firewall ?? maybe this will help.

Comment: I did it, it's not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the PMB.exe executable that is in charge of retrieving the installation file from Riot's server is unable to start on your machine.

You may try to :

- Get the original PBM software from Pando Networks website if available, check if there is a win 64 version eventually. You may want to uninstall any Pando Network software related to the PMB before doing so.
- Download the League of legends client again and try it again.
- Change the compatibility mode of the PMB.exe to 32-bit executable.